# How to unregister the Image Listener of the CarouselView to avoid Memory Leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks, carousel

In an Android application,

How to unregister the Image Listener of the CarouselView to avoid Memory Leak:
[CarouselView](https://github.com/sayyam/carouselview)

Some part of the code:
The following code is the class to define the Image Listener of the carouselview

```
 public class CarouselView_ImageListeners_Configuration_NewPage
    {
        final int[] sampleImages = {R.drawable.a1, R.drawable.koalasplash2,R.drawable.logo1,R.drawable.logo2};
        Context mContext;
        int ImageScaleType = 0;

        public void SetContext(Context mContext)
        {
            this.mContext = mContext;
        }

        public void SetImageScaleType(int ImageScaleType)
        {
            this.ImageScaleType = ImageScaleType;
        }

        public ImageListener imageListener_ScaleType = new ImageListener() {
            @Override
            public void setImageForPosition(int position, ImageView imageView) {

                Log.e("JFT", "QWEQQQ 1 =  "+ ImageScaleType );
                switch (ImageScaleType)
                {
                    case 0:
                        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
                    case 2:
                        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                        break;
                }
                Glide.with(mContext).load(sampleImages[position]).into(imageView);
                //Picasso.with(mContext).load(sampleImages[position]).into(imageView);
            }
        };
    }
```

And:
In this part of the code I sent the context

```
 final CarouselView_ImageListeners_Configuration_NewPage mBuild_M4_Configurations_NewPage_ImageListeners = new CarouselView_ImageListeners_Configuration_NewPage();
    mBuild_M4_Configurations_NewPage_ImageListeners.SetContext(mContext);
```

And:

```
mLayoutStruct.getLayout_carouselView().setImageListener(mBuild_M4_Configurations_NewPage_ImageListeners.imageListener_ScaleType);
```

Comment: Did you check there is memory leak? CarouselView is field of Activity and will be taken care by activity so once Activity going to be destroyed it will take care of cleanup.

Comment: I see Memory Leak by Leak Canary and it shows the Activity is leaked but it does not specify the cause of the leak so I'm not sure which part of the code is problematic

Comment: I cant see your actual code but if as per link shared,  make ImageListener imageListener global variable initialize in onCreate of activity and make it null in onDestroy{imageListener=null}

Do same with ViewListener viewListener

Comment: In the code, I didn't make ImageListener a global variable and initialized in the activity, I just initialize it in a class which is called from the activity, so this may be the problem?

Comment: I added some code

Comment: You are passing context to CarouselView_ImageListeners_Configuration_NewPage
That is the problem in my understanding.

SetContext(null) in onDestroy() of activity.
or  CarouselView_ImageListeners_Configuration_NewPage make it global variable in activity  and make it null in onDestroy.

Comment: @Mundroid, it did not work (imageListener=null &&  SetContext(null))

Comment: Utilizing leak canary the timer task of the carouselview is suspicious, what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was timer in CarouselView,
I set the interval to 0 then the leak is vanished